# Why does Flume need to have a AMQP source?

Tags: hadoop, rabbitmq, messaging, flume, apache-kafka

Flume has several third party plugins to support AMQP source.
Why would we want to send message to rabbitmq or qpid and then to flume and not directly to flume ?
Am i missing something ?

Also , in what cases i should use messaging queues like Qpid , rabbitMQ and when something like Flume ?
I read Qpid , RabbitMQ gurantees ordered delivery which is not important in my case.
Any other differences ?

Can we add channels and sink dynamically to a running flume agent ? Adding a new channel to a source with a file roll sink , it does not require any code change just a conf file change and a restart. Is there a way to do it dynamically i.e  without restarting of flume agent

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case basically. As you have mentioned, in your use case, ordered delivery is not important, then may be Flume will fit. Flume is actually faster because of this feature and it has a cheaper fault tolerance setup. [Check this link](https://github.com/cloudera/flume/wiki/FAQ#flume-has-weak-ordering-guarantees) for more details.

In addition, Flume fits well when dealing with Hadoop enviroment (HDFS as a sink), as it actually evolved from that. And you also see for the same reason use cases, where RabbitMQ (as source) messages are being pushed through Flume.

Comment: can we add channels and sink dynamically to a running flume agent ? say adding a new channel to a source with a file roll sink , it does not require any code change just a conf file change . Is there a way to do it dynamically i.e without restarting of flume agent

Comment: Yup, may be from the master with the web interface, so that you don't have to remote login and restart and stuff. See this link: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/UserGuide/#_configuring_a_node_via_the_master. I used flume a year and a half back, so not much into touch with this

Comment: Ya but flume-ng documentation  does not say anything about flume master. This one is an old documentation for older version

Comment: Is it? Check this link http://www.evanconkle.com/tag/flume-ng/ where flume master has been setup and should be available as an http interface. I might be outdated though.